# How to change the size of R tables in Jupyter?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

I have to use Jupyter notebook for a project and using R in there.
Created a `tableby()` object but because there are 6 columns and some continuous variable, table do not fit in. I used `tableby(Condition~.,data=InsuranceSex4, control=mycontrols,digits = 1)` and shorten the names of variables to barely fit.
Is there a function to shrink `table` in Jupyter?